# Pass dummy Parameter to SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql query and got stuck in middle of some query.

Issue:- my query where condition is like this 
"where new_FleetSeries in (@fleet)" now in report everything is working fine.
But i want to make this query run in SQL for testing and in order to test i have created on variable and manually filled the values something like below.

```
Declare @fleet varchar(150) SET @fleet= ('B777,B777F-200, B777F-200L')
```

Now if i select the same parameters from report my report gives me result but same parameters if i fill manually didnt gives me result in SQL.

Comment: What version of SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IN clause` must have values not only one string 
something like this

```
where new_FleetSeries in ('B777','B777F-200', 'B777F-200L')
```

so instead of filling a parameter , you have to concatenate those values to the original query